# Deploy web application to local juju enviroment

Tags: server, juju, configuration, webapps

I am new to juju. So far i have installed juju and configure in local Ubuntu server. I have web application and i want to deploy this web app into juju server. I read more articles but they said crate juju charm and deploy.

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-writing i read this one. But they used vanilla to deploy. So i need to deploy my web application. Can anyone tell me specific steps i need to follow.

Thanks

Sajith

Answer (score 1):

They didn't use Vanilla to deploy, they wrote the charm for Vanilla and deployed it. That is the correct guide to follow. The Juju hooks can be written in any language so you don't need to write it in bash if you aren't comfortable with it. Here is a charm which deploys the Ghost blogging platform written in JavaScript https://github.com/hatched/ghost-charm as an example